# Where can I ask questions regarding laptop maintenance?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I have some doubts regarding my laptop maintenance. Where can I ask such types of question?

Comment: Depends, what's your question exactly about?

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby Its about operating system installation. My laptop is not booting and I am not able re-install new os

Comment: That's not maintenance! In that case, as Martjin has said, Super User. But be warned, make it a good question! There are already too many "That thing does not boot, what do I do?" questions over there.

Answer (score 5):

Ask it on http://superuser.com.

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

Do check out the rest of the FAQ though; keep the question reasonably scoped.

Answer (score 4):

"Electronic device" is quite a broad term. If it's about trying to find out why your laptop isn't booting, then you can ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com) as Martijn Pieters [mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145011/133693).

If your question is a product recommendation/shopping question(Ex: Which processor should I buy etc) then it's offtopic for Super User and throughout the network.

For starters, have a look some of the [booting related questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot?sort=faq&pagesize=15) and search before asking. And mention your problem clearly, not just

> laptop not booting, What do?

Comment: As of 2019, Hardware Recommendations SE is currently in beta. https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com